# Retrofit Method invocation may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

Using Retrofit 2.3.0 I am getting the following message in Android Studio

[image]

Any suggestions on how I could remove this IDE error message. Thanks

Comment: Having a code that will never throw a NullPointerException?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068141/retrofit-android-method-invocation-getsuccess-may-produce-java-lang-nullpoin/46068517#46068517

Answer (score 12):

From the [**Response** documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html):

> ```
> @Nullable
> public T body()
> ```
>
> The deserialized response body of a successful response.

This means that `response.body()` can return null, and as a result, invoking `response.body().getItems()` can throw a `NullPointerException`. To avoid the warning message, check that `response.body() != null` before invoking methods on it.

### Edit

Discussion on another question revealed that my statements above are not as clear as they need to be. If the original code was:

```
mAdapter.addItems(response.body().getItems());
```

It will not be solved by wrapping in a null check like this:

```
if (response.body() != null) {
    mAdapter.addItems(response.body().getItems());
}
```

The linter (the thing generating the warning) has no way of knowing that each `response.body()` invocation is going to return the same value, so the second one will still be flagged. Use a local variable to solve this:

```
MyClass body = response.body();
if (body != null) {
    mAdapter.addItems(body.getItems());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and provide feedback soon.