# Retrofit Android: Method invocation 'getSuccess' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I am using Retroft and GSON for parsing the response.

My `onResponse` code is like below

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResultList> call, @NonNull Response<ResultList> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        if (response.body() != null && response.body().getSuccess() == 1) {
            ................
```

I am checking `response.body() != null` and also `response.isSuccessful()`.
Still I am getting warning in Android studio on line  `response.body().getSuccess()`.

How to avoid this warning?

I am using retrofit:2.3.0 and gson:2.8.1.
I already tried the solution on this question  ([Retrofit Method invocation may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422911/retrofit-method-invocation-may-produce-java-lang-nullpointerexception)
). But it was not working

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422911/retrofit-method-invocation-may-produce-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: @ Bapusaheb Shinde: I already tried. But it was not working. Same warning showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Response.body()` is declared with the `@Nullable` annotation, which means that its return value may be null. You must check that the returned value is not null before invoking methods if you want to avoid this warning.

Your question includes this code:

```
if (response.body() != null && response.body().getSuccess() == 1)
```

It sounds like you expect this to remove the warning, but it will not. This is because the linter has no way of knowing that the second invocation of `body()` will return the same value as the first invocation. Instead, write this:

```
ResultList body = response.body();
if (body != null && body.getSuccess() == 1) {
    ...
}
```